# Android : Background thread and screen awake, works in emulator not in device

Tags: android, android-emulator, background-process

In the application I have a background thread which downloads the data, sometimes no of records are very high. We display a progress bar to show a data

Suppose I am downloading 1000 records that takes about 1 to 5 mins depending upon network. The screen fades into black while the downloading process is on going and it even doesn't notify if any error occurred. To solve this I have applied this code

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

**What happens in emulator** : I have set screen time out to 30 seconds and than started downloading the data. Currently my network is slow and downloading is ongoing for last 30 mins but the screen hasn't faded out. I still can see everything on screen.

**What happens in device: [Tested in Samsung i5700]** : Screen time out is set to 30 seconds. The same code didn't run as it run in emulator. After 30 seconds screen fades into black and device is got locked.

Did I do anything wrong that doesn't let the code run on device as expected? Or there is any other thing that need to be handled explicitly if possible?

Comment: In your Emulator stay awake is checked,  (setting -> Applications -> Development).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the screen of the emulator doesn't fade because of your code?
Some days ago I discovered that the emulator won't lock the screen if the "device is plugged into AC".

Try disabling AC-connection via adb (Connect via telnet and enter "power ac off").

Comment: Well that may be the reason why this code in device is not working.. do you have any solution to make this work while device is not connected to ac??

Comment: I just tried it, too. Screen time out of 15 seconds... waited a minute, nothing happened...

Comment: Means your screen didn't fade while your device or emulator is not connected?